# Trying to return just the description in an array of instances of a class

Tags: javascript

So this is what I am trying to solve:

```js
class ViewRole {
  name
  description
  constructor(name, description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
  }
}

class NewRole {
  name;
  description;
  constructor(name, description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
  }
}

var armadilloRoles = [
  new NewRole('Billing', 'armadillo.organization.billing'),
  new NewRole('Doctor', 'armadillo.organization.doctor'),
  new NewRole('Nurse Practitioner', 'armadillo.organization.nursePractitioner'),
  new NewRole('Patient', 'armadillo.microurb.billing'),
  new NewRole('Microurb admin', 'armadillo.organization.admin'),
  new NewRole('Microurb admin', 'armadillo.organization.admin'),
  new NewRole('Microurb billing', 'armadillo.organization.billing'),
  new NewRole('Respiratory therapist', 'armadillo.microurb.respiratoryTherapist'),
  new NewRole('Microurb commercial contact', 'armadillo.microurb.practiceGrowthDirector')
];

var viewRoles = [];

for (var i = 0; i < armadilloRoles.length; i++) {
  const role = armadilloRoles[i];
  const viewRoleDto = new ViewRole(role.name, role.description);
  //  if (viewRoleDto[i].description.startsWith('armadillo.organization.')) {
  //      viewRoles.push(viewRoleDto[i]);
  //  }
  viewRoles.push(viewRole);
}
console.log(viewRoles);
```

I have tried a variety of ways of implementing an if conditional with a `startsWith()` method.

I want to return just the ones that have `armadillo.organization.` as the description.

Comment: `viewRoleDto` isn't an array, why are you subscripting it with `[i]`? Fix that and the code works.

Answer (score 0):

A good way would be to use `reduce` like this:

```
const matches = armadilloRoles.reduce(
  (prev, cur) =>
    cur.description.startsWith("armadillo.organization") ? [...prev, cur] : prev,
  []
);
```